# mod_rewrite enabled but does not work properly

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

About an hour ago, I Added

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule .+ %1.php [QSA,L]
```

to my `.htaccess` file. but It doesnt work. when I go to mywebsite.com/info or mywebsite.com/info/ it doesnt work (the page is info.php). the mod_rewrite is enabled - tested it by RewriteRule that redirected me to google from any page in my site.

I have no idea what's the problem.. maybe the code is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you're missing a `/` after `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`? Not sure at all, but it's the only thing that caught my eye

Comment: @Pekka, Tried it, not working.

Comment: hmm. Can you try dropping the second RewriteCond completely? Just to see whether it works then

Comment: @Pekka, got Internal Server Error when I removed it.

Comment: strange. I'm out of ideas for the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's what I needed for the rules to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ron

Try changing the last two lines to this:

```
RewriteCond %1.php -f
RewriteRule .+ %1.php [PT]
```

You'll need the `[PT]` in order for the PHP file to be processed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy takes about an hour to parse your newly uploaded .htaccess file. It's strange. But the file should work fine as is if you just wait.